# Django + Haystack: How to show the most common queries?

Tags: python, django

I would like to know if it is possible to print the most common queries. Here is my search_index.py:

```
class LinkIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    description = indexes.CharField(model_attr='description')
    pub_date = indexes.DateField(model_attr='pub_date')
    tags = indexes.CharField(model_attr='tags')


    def get_model(self):
        return Link
```

Can someone give me one idea of how to do it?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a feature that will be nice if somebody speaks up. I use solr which has more_like_this, but I'm not aware of ranking based on popularity.  I typically have to setup a different table and or give a tag to my model object to verify this is a popular item etc...

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion you could store each query in the database (it could be some NoSQL db) and you could aggregate them to count the most popular queries.